# C Programming - Average

Tags: c, printf, scanf, integer-division

Okay I'm entirely stuck here and I do apologise if this inconviences you guys in any way but I need your help.

I'm currently learning C by myself and slowly getting there, started yesterday. So I thought I would give myself a task on having the user input 3 numbers and the program would have to find the average number between those three.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int firstnum, secnum, thirnum, finalnum;

    printf("Enter the first number \n");
    scanf("%f",&firstnum);

    printf("Enter the second number \n");
    scanf("%s",&secnum);

    printf("Enter the third number \n");
    scanf("%t",&thirnum);

    finalnum = (firstnum +secnum+thirnum)/3;
    printf("The average value is: " finalnum);

return finalnum;

}
```

Comment: `"%d"` is the appropriate format specifier to `scanf` or  `printf` an `int`.

Comment: Use `printf("The average value is: %d", finalnum);`, but beware that you're performing integer division (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). Consider floats.

Comment: So I would put floats in with the 'final num'?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an interactive tutorial nor a substitute for C programming books/studies. You'll have to study the basics mentioned in chapter 1 of your book. Also, when asking a question on SO, clearly state what problems you're having, not just dump some code and say "it's not working". In this case you get compiler errors, so you should have posted them with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reading integers or floats: Correct format specifier**

For integers you'll need `%d`and for doubles `%lf`. Read more about those elsewhere.

E.g.

```
scanf("%d",&firstnum);
```

**Printing integers or floats**

E.g.

```
printf("The average value is: %d", finalnum);
```

**Avoid integer division: casting  or all floats**

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

E.g.

```
double finalnum = (firstnum +secnum+thirnum)/3.0;
```

Or use floats for all types.

```
double firstnum, secnum, thirnum, finalnum;
```

**Return 0 for success in main**

```
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix linking with the comments made by [harre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4786466/harre) and [Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646887/klas-lindb%C3%A4ck). Thank you both.

I changed my format specifiers to %d as suggested. I then changed my **printf** line a little bit more.

I then tried to make a float with my **int > finalnum** but it didn't work. All this did was continously return the average as '0' so I placed **finalnum** back as an int. This is how the code looks now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int firstnum, secnum, thirnum;
    int finalnum;

    printf("Enter the first number \n");
    scanf("%d",&firstnum);

    printf("Enter the second number \n");
    scanf("%d",&secnum);

    printf("Enter the third number \n");
    scanf("%d",&thirnum);

    finalnum = (firstnum + secnum + thirnum)/3;
    printf("The average value is: %d", finalnum);

return finalnum;

}
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: This still isn't what you want. You're still doing integer division here. To do what you want, try the following: 1) Replace all `int` with `float`. 2) Replace all `%d` with `%f`. 3) Replace `3` with `3.0` (though this part isn't strictly necessary but technically correct). The code will then behave as you expect.

Comment: Yeah float now works for some reason. Lesson learnt - use float when not doing integer division. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use float instead of int to get decimal precision
otherwise the finalnum would get rounded off

use this for printing float
printf("The average value is: %f",finalnum);

for more on printf you can refer this link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: This is not a round off issue but a result of integer division.